# Dependancy injection in two layers in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get more and more familliar with DI and IoC. At this moment I understand the concept and implementation of DI with the controllers in an MVC application. But assume I have a layered application. 
The Controllers call businesslogic classes and the businesslogic clases call the repository classes.

How do I setup the second layer, the businesslogic to repository part with DI. This ensures I can test on different levels in my application. What I don't want to do is passing the dependancy to the repository from the controllers.

Hope someone can give some hints on this.

Patrick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimalistic example how to implement using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). This is not absolute truth about DI/IoC, just a brief example how it *could* be done.

**Configuration**

```
// repositories
base.Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>();

// services
base.Bind<IMyServices>().To<MyServices>();
```

When ever `IMyRepository` is used then it will use concrete implementation `MyRepository`.

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyServices _myServices;

    public AnimalController(IMyServices myServices)
    {
        _myServices = myServices;
    }

    // your actions
}
```

Again, inside `MyService` there is a similar pattern (constructor injection)

**Service**

```
public class MyServices : IMyServices
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public MyServices(IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        _myRepository.PleaseDoSomething();
    }
}
```

Also remember that there are lots of other things in the ASP.NET MVC where IoC can be used:

- localization
- authorization
- model metadata provider (for example localized error messages)
- custom model binders
- controller factory
- etc.

**Update**

In the example code there was a bug. Dependency injection was not done in the service. Now it should be correct.

**Update 2**

I think it's highly recommended to use NuGet packages to bootstrap your app. Saves time, might apply some "best practices", other projects will get similar base etc. Here are some instructions for different IoC's + MVC 3

- [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration)
- [StructureMap](http://ardalis.com/How-Do-I-Use-StructureMap-with-ASP.NET-MVC-3)

Comment: +1 for the examples, which show that the classes just use constructor injection and this could be done manually without needing any DI containers intervention at all.

Comment: @SamHolder Exactly, even if sometimes it seems that containers do "magic", everything can still be done manually. I think features of all these tools are really good, it's just matter of taste and quality of documentation which one to pick.

Comment: @Patrick Great! Let me know if you have questions. I highly recommend book called "Art of Unit Testing", it covers these topics with C# examples

Answer (score 2):

put simply, each layer in the hierarchy asks for the dependencies on the next layer down via a constructor argument, which is an interface.

your controllers ask for their dependencies on a business logic through their constructors. They do this by a dependency on an interface to the business logic not by asking for a particular implementation.  You create an interface for your business logic class, and inject an implementation of that interface into your controller, this can be done manually or you can get a DI container to do it for you.  Your controller knows nothing about the repository classes (or any other dependencies of any implementation of the business logic), only about the interface to the business logic class on which it depends.

You then rinse and repeat on the business logic concrete classes.

You create an interface for your repository classes and the business logic classes which require those ask for them through their constructor, and then you again inject the dependency in either manually or via a DI container.

You application should have a composition root where all of this setup takes place, which is where you either manually wire up your dependencies (create the lowest objects first and then pass them in to the constructors of the higher up objects as you create those), or you configure the container with the details of the implementation of various interfaces you have, so that it can then use that information to correctly construct objects which have dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A DI container just creates and resolves dependencies for types it's configured to. It is unrelated to how do you design your application layers. Why don't you want to pass the repository where it's needed?! Those objects depend on an abstraction and not on implementation.

You configure the DI container to serve a certain instance of Repository anywhere where it's required. The controller receives the repository instance, which then can be passed on to the business layer to be used.

Decoupling means an object doesn't depend on implementation details, that's it. Testing is possible because the dependecies are expressed as interfaces and you can mock them.

Comment: I think the OP was meaning that he doesn't want to pass the repository to the controller, just so it can be passed to the business logic classes.  Well I assume so anyway...